# UITableView resizing when adding item

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Im currently working with an UITableView and I´m resizing it with the following lines of code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    [self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 177)];
}];
```

When it has been resized it looks like this:

[image]

But when I add an item to the table it changes back to its original position. There is no methods/functions to move it back to that position which makes this very confusing.

I have figured out that this only occurs when I´m using a custom cell, more specific when adding elements (UILabel, buttons, etc) to it.

Any suggestions what can be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Check the UITableView inside your NIB (or storyboard). Go to the size inspector and click the red Autosizing arrows to turn off your UITableView's Autosizing. Usually UITableViews are Autosized by default in the nib.

**OR**

Check to see if Autolayout is enabled on your ViewController. You may have to turn it off to keep the UITableView from resizing.

1. Select the ViewController in the Storyboard or NIB
2. Click the 'File Inspector' tab on the right hand side of your Xcode window
3. Under the 'Interface Builder Document' section, uncheck 'Use Autolayout'

Hopefully this helps someone. Autolayout sometimes causes frustration like this for me.

**OR** If Autolayout is necessary for your project, animate using a transform instead of the frame like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
     self.tableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0f, 2.0f);
}];
```

Comment: Just tried that but in the new storyboard I have to to select a resizer. I also tried to do it programatically with setAutorezisingMask to none and setAutorezisesSubviews to NO and nothing works.. Any other suggestions? Thanks for the help btw